# Is it possible to have 1 slave server with multiple master?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, master-slave-replication

Here is my set of master server:
DbServer1 - 10.1.0.1
DbServer2 - 10.1.0.2
DbServer3 - 10.1.0.3
DbServer4 - 10.1.0.4

and my replica server would be on 10.1.0.5

Is this doable if I create 4 instances of MySQL on a single server with different ports? But keeping in mind that all of my Master are using the default port which is 3306

Comment: What you have asked is technically possible as per the answer below. The lack of background information in your question however means its impossible to assess if its a good idea for you. The "4 instances on a single server" make it ambigious what you are trying to acheive. Edit the question to include this and maybe a simplier solution can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run on different port and configure replication through master.
If you have different table name or db name in all master, you can for with **multi source replica** in that case you just need to install single instance for replica node of all masters. You can go through [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html) and comment if have any doubt and need more clarification.

Comment: Hi @Rohit how should my replica server specs should be? I am testing 2 sources both with 2vcpu and 8gb RAM.

Comment: specs depends on how fast writes on master and you can afford slave lag on that node or not. Initially you can use 1.5x spec with high disk IOPs. Further, you can tweek replication parameters as per need.

Answer (score 0):

[Multi-source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html) (or [MariaDB multi-source](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/multi-source-replication/)) allows for master servers to one replica.

Yes multiple instances are possible on a single server if they have distinct ports and data directories.